# Get storage used by a SharePoint site day to day

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, storage

Is there way to get SharePoint storage used by each sites on day today basics? I can get break down for SharePoint storage for all sites in total but I would like to see it see break down for each sites over period of a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge, we can only view the amount of storage being used(all sites) by date:
[image]

Or the amount of storage being used on each site:
[image]

I'm afraid it is currently not supported to get SharePoint storage used by each sites on day today basics. You can provide your feedback here: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/06735c62-321c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472. Microsoft would consider rolling out such feature if it is highly voted.